# MySQL - how to backup database to a different server?

Tags: backup, mysql, myisam

I have 2 databases with MyISAM tables which are updated once a week. They are quite big in size (one DB is 2GB and the other is 6GB). I currently back them up once a week with mysqldump and keep the last 2 weeks' worth of .sql dumps on the same server where the DBs are running.

I would like, however, to be able to dump the backups to another server, as they are taking up server space unnecessarily. What is the best way to achieve this? If possible, I would like to keep the databases running during the backup. (no inserts or updates take place during the backup process, just selects).

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: There is a million ways and protocols to get the mysqldump output to another server - the question is which method is the best for your setup. To get an answer to that, you should elaborate more on what you are running (Network structure, OS....)

Comment: Also, this question is more suitable on SO's sister site, serverfault.com. Voting to migrate there (no need to do anything, migration will take place automatically)

Comment: Hi Pekka, thanks for your comment. I am using Linux on the live environment and Windows is the destination where I want to move the backups. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Were I you, I would create a script that did the backup and then sent the backup elsewhere. I know that is kind of what you are asking how to so, but you left out some things that would be good to know, such as what OS are your two systems running?

Of they are both windows, you could mount a network drive and have the backup dump there (or copy the dump there). If they are linux servers I would recommend copying it across using the scp command. If it is a mix then it gets fun and tricky.

If you are working with linux servers, the following guide should walk you through the process of backup. [Click me!](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html)

If you are still scratching your head after reading that, let me know what kind of OSes you are rolling with and I can provide more detailed instructions.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. The LIVE server environment is Linux while I would like to move the dump files (i.e. copy and delete, without manual intervention) to a Windows environment (my home PC). Also, are there any free tools to automate this process? Thanks!